# EPIC (Eclipse Perl) occurrence color poor visibility

Tags: perl, epic

I came to like eclipse as perl ide the last weeks.
But the occurrence-highlighting of the perl/EPIC plugin is bugging me, because I can't change the color or don't know how (and didn't found a solution anywhere).

I can't see a "color" option in the EPIC/perl configuration (see screenshot below)
I already changed all settings in `"General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > *...occurrence...*"` to "dashed box" but in the perl-script still "highlighting" is used.

[image: this is really hard to see]

**Question:** How do I change the color settings in for perl syntax highlighting? Maybe there is a file to edit this?

Comment: Having the exact same problem at the moment. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: sorry, no I didn't found a solution. I think I switched to MS VS Code at that time :/